# Calling timer_tick function give me No overload for 'timer2_Tick' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I am trying to give a label as flashlight effect. I have created a function called `flashlight`. Here is some part of the code

```cs
public void Flashlight(Label lable)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int one = rand.Next(0, 255);
    int two = rand.Next(0, 255);
    int three = rand.Next(0, 255);
    int four = rand.Next(0, 255);

    lable.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(one, two, three, four);
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox2.Size = new Size(82, 82);
    pictureBox3.Size = new Size(82, 82);
    pictureBox3.Enabled = false;
    timer2.Tick += (sender, args) => timer2_Tick(sender, args, label1);
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e,Label l)
{
    Flashlight(l);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here ? this is the part of code where I am stuck in. I am getting error

> CS0123    No overload for 'timer2_Tick' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

Comment: This should works fine. Make sure you have done a Clean/Rebuild solution once.

Comment: Tried to clean and rebuild the solution but not working :( Getting the same error while trying to rebuild the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `timer2_Tick` in somewhere else in your code, it should be inside `Form1.Designer.cs` and then delete it, that's because you've already declared it by double clicking on your timer. So you need to delete the following line after you've found it:

```
this.timer2.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer2_Tick);
```

As a shorter way, to find this line, after you've rebuilt your project and then in the `Error` List window double click on error which says:

> CS0123  No overload for 'timer2_Tick' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

And then delete that line.

Comment: thanks work successfully. any way to make it shorter like functions? cause I have to call it somewhere else too

Comment: @AtikRahman Actually you can use some data structure like arrays instead of declaring four separate variables one,two,three,four as a good start to refactor your code.